# Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, frontend

i learning react and the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON" appeared

this is the part of the code that involves JSON(two files):

1* file:

```
const register = async (data) => {

    const config = requestConfig("POST", data)

    try {
        
        const res = await fetch(api + "/users/register", config).then((res) => res.json()).catch((err) => err);

        if(res) {
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(res))
            
        };

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    };
};
```

import 1* file in 2* and continue:

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) 

const initialState = {
    user: user ? user : null,
    error: false,
    success: false,
    loading: false,
};
```

...

I realized that the error is in the part "JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))"

with what I researched apparently the creation of the object "user" in trycatch isn't working,
as a beginner in both react and programming, I don't know what to do.

if necessary, analyze the 4 related files: https://codesandbox.io/s/error-bgudd2
(*this project has a backend*)

thanks, and sorry for the awful english :P

wezetti,

Comment: Don't mix `await` with `.then()` callbacks. Use one or the other.

Comment: agree with Pointy, you are using callback in the async function

Comment: If the error is coming from `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))`, have you tried to set a fallback value for when the `user` key isn't initalised? E.g. `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user") || null)`.